# Redirect pagination urls to parent

Tags: nginx

I am trying to redirect URLs ending in `/whatever/page/X` to `/whatever`

Here is what I have so far, but it redirects to the home page:

`rewrite /page/([0-9]+)/$ /$1 redirect;`

This is directly in my server block. Mostly written from what I can piece together, I'm not great with Nginx redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Just found it:

`rewrite /(.+)/page/([0-9]+)/$ /$1 redirect;`